# How to register inherited sub class in admin.py file in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-inheritance

- Project Name : fusion
- App Name : admin_lte
- Python 3.7
- Django 2
- MySql

Question is "I want to register sub model in django admin-panel",when i write code for model registration in admin.py file that time occurred below error.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The model Device is abstract, so it cannot be registered with admin.
>
> **NOTE : I used multiple separated model file.**

**device.py (Model File)**

```
from django.db import models

class Device(models.Model):
device_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
price = models.IntegerField()
status =  models.CharField(max_length=10, default="SOLD")
issues = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="No Issues")

class Meta:
    abstract = True

def __str__(self):
    return 'Device_type:{0} Price:{1}'.format(self.device_type,self.price)


#Inheritance Concept
class Laptop(Device):
   pass
   class Meta:
       db_table = "laptop"

class Desktop(Device):
   pass
   class Meta:
       db_table = "Desktop"

class Mobile(Device):
    pass
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Mobile"
```

---

**__init__.py File**

```
from django_adminlte.models.employee import Employee
from django_adminlte.models.device import Device
```

---

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import Employee
from.models import Device

admin.site.register (Employee)
admin.site.register (Device)
```

---

I want to show sub model (Desktop,Laptop,Mobile) in admin panel so admin can add some data from admin panel.

---

[Project Structure Image :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtoRz.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see in your code `Device` is a `abstract model`. So, we should not register it because abstract models do not have associated tables in databases.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Employee, Laptop, Mobile, Desktop

admin.site.register(Employee)
admin.site.register(Laptop)
admin.site.register(Mobile)
admin.site.register(Desktop)
```

Comment: Getting this error :  ImportError: cannot import name 'Laptop' from 'django_adminlte.models' (C:\fusion\django_adminlte\models\__init__.py), can i add subclass details in __init__.py file ?

Comment: @ParthJani plz update your project structure in your question

Comment: Please check Project Structure Image ,i just atteched in body area.

Comment: issues has been solved ,thanks a lot ,i just edit  this line in __init__.py file `from django_adminlte.models.device import Laptop, Mobile, Desktop`  and all sub models display in admin panel and its work proper ,Again Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also got a problem when trying to generate an admin CRUD for a class inheriting from an abstract class. But the cause was different so I'll leave my case here in case it helps someone else.

In my case, the problem was that I forgot to make the abstract class inherit from django's models.Model.

Example Code:

time.py

```
from django.db import models

from applications.utils import UniqueNameMixin


class Month(UniqueNameMixin):
    starting_date = models.DateField()
    ending_date = models.DateField()


class TimeSensible(models.Model):  # Here '(models.Model)' was missing.
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    month = models.ForeignKey(Month, models.PROTECT)
```

transaction.py

```
from django.db import models

from applications.core.models.cash_flow import Concept
from applications.core.models.financial_position import Account
from applications.core.models.time import TimeSensible


class Transaction(models.Model, TimeSensible):
    concept = models.ForeignKey(Concept, models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, models.PROTECT)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} - {} - {}'.format(self.month, self.concept, self.amount, self.account)
```

The error I got:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The model Transaction is abstract, so it cannot be registered with admin.
```