# Registering derived child class of abstract class in admin.py in django 2.2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

Does anyone know, how to register **child class derived from abstract class** in  admin.py (the abstract class is in file abstract_models.py file) I tried major solution in the web but does not seem to work. It is possible as pointed by various contributors but don't know what I am doing wrong!

My folder structure is like this

'''

```
gaasc/ <- project folder

     contain urls.py, admin.py,models.py,etc

gaasc_apps/<- contains all apps

    core/
       abstract_models.py
       models.py
       admin.py,...

    about_app/
      models.py, 
      admin.py
      urls.py
```

'''

I am trying to leverage abstract class inside **core app** to models inside **about_app app**. Yes, between different apps.

Steps followed:

1. create abstract_models.py and define abstract class
2. import it in core/models.py

3.import the abstract class from core/models.py inside about_app/models.py

4. register the class in about_app/models.py to admin.py(in about_app/)

**abstract_models.py** file(inside core/abstract_models.py) has

```
import uuid
from django.db import models


class AbstractTimeStampModel(models.Model):
     """TimeStampModel that holds created_date and updated_date       field"""
     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     created_date = models.DateTimeField("Created date", auto_now_add=True)
     updated_date = models.DateTimeField("Updated date", auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.created_date

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AbstractTextAreaOnly(AbstractTimeStampModel):
     """Abstract class for textfield"""

    about = models.TextField(
        verbose_name="Description",
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "Textonly class-"+self.id

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_date']
```

**models.py** in core/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .abstract_models import (
      AbstractTextAreaOnly,
)
```

Now I want to use this abstract class in about_app/
So my derived class in **models.py** inside **about_app/models.py** looks:

```
  from django.db import models
  from gaasc_apps.core.models import(
      AbstractTextAreaOnly,
  )

  class GeneralInformation(AbstractTextAreaOnly):
     '''
     Gives general information of college
     '''

     class Meta():
         db_table = "general_information"
         verbose_name="General information"
         ordering=['created_date']
```

**What I tried:**

I tried to registering using following ways:

**method1:**

in admin.py in **about_app/admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import (
    GeneralInformation,
)

@register(GeneralInformation)
class GeneralInformationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

**method 2:**

in about_app/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import (
    GeneralInformation,
)

class GeneralInformationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass

admin.site.register(GeneralInformation,GeneralInformationAdmin)
```

**method3:**

in about_app/admin.py

```
  ......
  class GeneralInformationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     readonly_fields = ('id','about','created_date','updated_date')
     list_display=('id','about','created_date')
     fieldsets=[
        ('Id',{'fields':['id']}),
        ('About',{'fields':['about']}),
        ('Created_Date',{'fields':['created_date']}),
     ]

     admin.site.register(GeneralInformation,GeneralInformationAdmin)
```

With all this solution GeneralInformation is not shown in admin panal/dashboard of django.
The solution seems to be simple but I don't know why its not working?
Some solution I tried are here:

[How to register inherited sub class in admin.py file in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514324/how-to-register-inherited-sub-class-in-admin-py-file-in-django)

[Django admin model Inheritance is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376102/django-admin-model-inheritance-is-it-possible)

[Register abstract model in admin django 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026203/register-abstract-model-in-admin-django-1-6)

VERSION:
Django-2.2
python-3.6

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the  problem , it was simple
we need to define config setting in each apps. Due to lack of config setting and perticular directory structure it was not able to read it.E.g.

in **about_app/__init__.py** :

```
default_app_config = "gaasc_apps.about_app.apps.AboutAppConfig"
```

and in **about_app/apps.py** we should have like this

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AboutAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'gaasc_apps.about_app'
    verbose_name="about application"

    def ready(self):
        pass
```